# Dimensions of a bar when it is subjected to axial pull

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, civil-engineering

Determine the change in dimensions of a rectangular bar of length 2 m, width 200 mm, and thickness 100 mm, when it is subjected to an axial pull of 20 kN in the direction of its length.

Take $E = 2\times10^5\text{ N/mm}^2$ and $\mu = 0.3$.

I have gotten up to $\delta L = 0.01$. Then using $\mu = \dfrac{δb/b}{δL/L}$, I got $\delta b = \dfrac{\mu bL}{δL}$, which is 0.3×200×2000/0.01 = 12million!

I don't know where I have mistaken but it is frustrating me.

Comment: Please show your effort in working towards a solution, then people may help.

Comment: I have gotten up to δL = 0.01

Comment: then using μ = (δb/b)/(δL/L) ; I got δb = μbL/δL ; which is = 0.3×200×2000/0.01 = 12million!!!! I don't know where I have mistaken but it is frustrating me. I don't have a tutor. please help.

Answer (score 1):

Let's do it over.
First we calculate the tension stress. $$\sigma=P/A=\frac{20kN}{100*200}=1N/mm^2  $$

then as per definition of Young modulus,

$$ \epsilon=\frac{\sigma}{E}=\frac{1N}{2×10^5}=0.000005 $$
and 
$$ lateral\ shrinkage=\mu*0.000005= 0.00000166$$
And then
$$200*0.00000166= 0.000332mm  $$

the amount the 200mm side narrows is small, 33/100000mm.